# Execute icacls in PowerShell to grant access to a file share for domain computer

Tags: powershell, permissions, share, icacls

I wonder how to uses `icacls` within a PowerShell script for setting up permissions on a fileshare for a computeraccount for e.g. Domain\myServer$.

This is what I'm trying:

```
$ComputerAccount = "domain\myServer$"
$Folder = "\\TestServer\TestShare\folder1"
$rule = $ComputerAccount+':(M),(OI),(CI)'
$resICacls = Invoke-Expression "icacls $folder /grant $rule"
```

I got this error message:

```
Invoke-Expression : At line:1 char:83
+ ... ant Domain\myServer$:(M),(OI),(CI)
+                    ~~

Variable reference is not valid. '$' was not followed by a valid variable name
character. Consider using ${} to delimit the name.
At c:\Binary\testacl.ps1:12 char:26
+             $resICacls = Invoke-Expression "icacls $folder /grant $rule"
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidVariableReference,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

I tried different variants of escaping the `$` but found no solution.
Anyone haves a hint how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

Try using the call operator (`&`) or `cmd /c` instead of `Invoke-Expression`:

```
& icacls $folder /grant $rule
```

```
cmd /c icacls $folder /grant $rule
```

or use `Get-Acl`/`Set-Acl` for changing permissions:

```
$permissions = 'Modify'
$inheritance = 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit'

$acl = Get-Acl -Path $folder
$ace = New-Object Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule ($ComputerAccount, $permissions, $inheritance, 'InheritOnly', 'Allow')
$acl.AddAccessRule($ace)
Set-Acl -AclObject $acl -Path $folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke-Expression -Command:`icacls foldername /grant groupName:"(CI)(OI)M"`

This works fine. So I guess that if you will put the command into single quote (i.e. `''`) it will work. For example:

```
$ComputerAccount = "domain\myServer$"
Invoke-Expression -Command:"icacls $ComputerAccount /grant GroupName:'(CI)(OI)M'"
```